# Turn Scala Anorm record into a specific object

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

Using `findBy` as seen below, I can search the `Authentications` table for a record by `key` and `value`

```
def findBy(key: String, value: String): Any = DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
  SQL("select * from authentications where {key}={value} limit 1").on('key -> key, 'value -> value)
}
```

Example:

```
Authentication.findByMe("email", "toot@toot.com")
```

Returns:

```
res1: Any = SimpleSql(SqlQuery(select * from authentications where ?=? limit 1,List(key, value),None),List((key,ParameterValue(email,anorm.ToStatement$$anon$3@4ca9aed5)), (value,ParameterValue(toot@toot.com,anorm.ToStatement$$anon$3@18154945))),<function1>)
```

How can I turn it back into an Authentication object? An object with all the fields I got back from the query.

I've tried the following, but I can't get passed a nullable object error when there's there's something null in one of the columns.  I can't figure out how to put to use the solutions offered [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaAnorm)

```
val authentication_parser =
  get[String]("email") ~
  get[String]("encrypted_password") ~
  get[String]("user_id") ~
  get[String]("token") ~
  get[Date]("created_at") ~
  get[Date]("updated_at")

val authentication = {
  authentication_parser map {
    case email~encrypted_password~user_id~token~created_at~updated_at => Authentication(email, encrypted_password, user_id, token, created_at, updated_at)
  }
}
```

Using it like so:

```
def findBy(key: String, value: String): Any = DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
  SQL("select * from authentications where {key}={value} limit 1").on('key -> key, 'value -> value).as(authentication *)
}
```

I'm also new to Scala, so I've been riddled with problems like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any column that is nullable in your table should be an `Option` in your `Authentication` object. For example, if your table is something like this:

```
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`encrypted_password` varchar(255) NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`token` varchar(255) NULL,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime NULL
```

Then you should have:

```
case class Authentication(email: String, password: Option[String], userId: Int, token: Option[String], createdAt: Date, updatedAt: Option[Date])
```

Your parser would look like:

```
val authentication_parser = {
   get[String]("email") ~
   get[Option[String]]("encrypted_password") ~
   get[String]("user_id") ~
   get[Option[String]]("token") ~
   get[Date]("created_at") ~
   get[Option[Date]]("updated_at") map {
       case email~encrypted_password~user_id~token~created_at~updated_at => 
           Authentication(email, encrypted_password, user_id, token, created_at, updated_at)
   }
}
```

If for some reason you don't want to use `Option` in your `Authentication` class, then use `getOrElse` in the map portion and fill it in with default values (much uglier):

```
case email~encrypted_password~user_id~token~created_at~updated_at => 
           Authentication(email, encrypted_password.getOrElse(""), user_id, token.getOrElse(""), created_at, updated_at.getOrElse(new Date())
```

For the paranoid, you may want to exclude the hashed password from the parser when retrieving from the database:

```
val authentication_parser = {
   get[String]("email") ~
   get[String]("user_id") ~
   get[Option[String]]("token") ~
   get[Date]("created_at") ~
   get[Option[Date]]("updated_at") map {
       case email~user_id~token~created_at~updated_at => 
           Authentication(email, None, user_id, token, created_at, updated_at)
   }
}
```

I would also suggest that you change your `.as()` parameter. `SQL("....").on(...).as(authentication_parser *)` will parse to `List[Authentication]`. Since you're using `LIMIT 1` in your query, it would be better to use `authentication_parser.single` (parses to `Authentication`) or `authentication_parser.singleOpt` (parses to `Option[Authentication]`). `singleOpt` is really the way to go for single records, as `single` will raise an exception if nothing is found.

Lastly, you ought to make the return type of your function something other than `Any`. (whatever matches the parser) Sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: Wish I'd had this explanation when I started out ;)

Comment: Now I'm getting the error when creating an authentication, type mismatch because Option[String] is different than String
`[error]  found   : String
[error]  required: Option[String]
[error]         val authentication = new Authentication(u.email, u.password.bcrypt, user.id, token , now, now)` Also, phenomenal answer

Comment: Looking at it more closely, would I just have to initialize my `String`s as `Option[String]`s?  In that case I might go with the `getOrElse` method

Comment: Following my example you would need `new Authentication(u.email, Some(u.password.bcrypt), user.id, Some(token), now, (now))`. To create an `Option`, you need to either declare it `None` or `Some(value)`.

Comment: How do you get access to `get` ? I get the following error `Compilation error[not found: value get]`

Comment: @ThomasPotaire `get` is in the `SqlParser` object. So either `import anorm.SqlParser._` or use `SqlParser.get`